# Python validation to test for multiple criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation

Edit: other than things like int, str, input, print - I cannot use inbuilt functions

I have scoured the world wide web, including stack overflow, but cannot find the help I need.

Essentially what I am looking to do is have a user input a binary number and the program will return it in decimal format.

The input needs to be validated against multiple criteria:

1. It must be an integer
2. It must only contain 1's or 0's - it can contain any combination of 0s and 1s but it cannot contain any number except 0s or 1s
3. It cannot be 0 (i.e. it must be > 0)

If those 3 conditions are met then it will run the code to convert the binary input into a decimal number.

I have tried so many different things that I have lost track of them but this is what I have at the moment and it is obviously not working.

I cannot get it so that the validation conditions ALL loop until ALL 3 are met before moving into the conversion code. Here is my latest attempt:

```
#Option 2 Binary to Decimal function
def Binary_to_Decimal(binary_number):
    while binary_number == '0':
        print("Please enter a number greater than 0.")
        binary_number = input("Input a binary number: ")
    decimal_input = 0
    for digit in str(binary_number):
        decimal_input = decimal_input*2 + int(digit)
    print("The decimal value of the number is", decimal_input)

User_Choice = str(input('What would you like to do [1,2,3,4]? '))

play_again = True

while play_again == True:
    if User_Choice == "2":
        print('In command 2 – convert to decimal')
        binary_number = input("Input a binary number: ")
        pending_val = True
        while pending_val == True:
            try:
                input_val = int(binary_number)
            except ValueError:
                print("Input was not a binary number")
                binary_number = input("Input a binary number: ")
            else:
                pending_val = False

            for item in binary_number:
                if item not in {'0', '1'}:
                    print("Please make sure your number contains digits 0-1 only.")
                    binary_number = input("Input a binary number: ")

            if binary_number == '0':
                print("Please enter a number greater than 0.")
                binary_number = input("Input a binary number: ")
            
            else:
                pending_val = False
    
        else:
            Binary_to_Decimal(binary_number)
        User_Choice = str(input('What would you like to do [1,2,3,4]? '))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make your input simpler, handling difference input on each condition is confusing. Try use `continue` and `break` in a loop, this will help you a lot.

```
#Option 2 Binary to Decimal function
def Binary_to_Decimal(binary_number):
    while binary_number == '0':
        print("Please enter a number greater than 0.")
        binary_number = input("Input a binary number: ")
    decimal_input = 0
    for digit in str(binary_number):
        decimal_input = decimal_input*2 + int(digit)
    print("The decimal value of the number is", decimal_input)

User_Choice = str(input('What would you like to do [1,2,3,4]? '))

play_again = True

while play_again == True:
    if User_Choice == "2":
        print('In command 2 – convert to decimal')
        while True:
            # Only use one input on a loop
            binary_number = input("Input a binary number: ")
            
            # It must be an integer
            try:
                input_val = int(binary_number)
            except ValueError:
                print("Input was not a binary number")
                continue
            
            # It must only contain 1's or 0's - it can contain any combination of 0s and 1s 
            # but it cannot contain any number except 0s or 1s
            if len(binary_number.replace('0', '').replace('1', '')) > 0:
                print("Please make sure your number contains digits 0-1 only.")
                continue
            
            # It cannot be 0 (i.e. it must be > 0)
            if not int(binary_number) > 0:
                print("Please enter a number greater than 0.")
                continue
            
            # if all condition is passed, do the main method
            Binary_to_Decimal(binary_number)
            break
        
        User_Choice = str(input('What would you like to do [1,2,3,4]? '))
```

Comment: Thank you! We're not supposed to use break or continue in our code but at this point I am so over it that if this works I will use it :)

Comment: Update: this worked so huge thanks for your help! Life saver.
Would you mind stepping me through what exactly this line does:
'if len(binary_number.replace('0', '').replace('1', '')) > 0:'

.. I see it is looking for 0s or 1s and there must be more of x1 of them? but which part specifically is instructing that it must not contain anything other than 0 or 1?

Comment: operate the input as string, then replace all "0" and "1" in that string. If every single char in the string is "0" or "1" it will result a blank string `""`, `len("") ` is 0. If there are other numbers, it will be stay on that string so the `len` will be more than 0.

Comment: ex: `"000012300".replace('0', '').replace('1', '')` will result `"23"`, `len("23")` is 2